# Mongodb read-write time increases after using WiredTiger

Tags: mongodb, performance, wiredtiger, storage-engines

Am trying to compare the read-write time of mongodb with and without WiredTiger. I found that for both read and write, mongodb with WiredTiger is taking more time than without WiredTiger. I am using node-mongo program for testing.

From what I understand, the performance should improve after using wiredtiger.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There are use cases in which the mmapv1 storage engine will outperform WiredTiger, and vice-versa. Can you give us details about your setup, version, document structure, and tests?

Comment: It's probably easier to discuss this sort of question on mongodb-user google group.  A lot more information about your workload and hardware would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

WiredTiger has better throughput due to ability to handle higher concurrency.  It does not have better latency on single threaded workload.

When you run your tests single-threaded, or on a host with few processors, you should not expect WiredTiger to be faster than MMAPv1.